# Scrapy not downloading images and getting pipeline error

Tags: python, scrapy

I have this code

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def get_media_requests(self, item, info):
            for image_url in item['image_urls']:
                yield Request(image_url)
```

and this is the spider subclassed from BaseSpider. This basespider is giving me nightmare

```
def parse(self, response):

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    sites = hxs.select('//strong[@class="genmed"]')
    items = []


    for site in sites[:5]:

        item = PanduItem()
        item['username'] = site.select('dl/dd/h2/a').select("string()").extract()
        item['number_posts'] = site.select('dl/dd/h2/em').select("string()").extract()
        item['profile_link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()



        request =  Request("http://www.example/profile.php?mode=viewprofile&u=5",
        callback = self.parseUserProfile)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        return request
```

---

```
 def parseUserProfile(self, response):

        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//div[@id="current')
        myurl = sites[0].select('img/@src').extract()

        item = response.meta['item']

        image_absolute_url = urljoin(response.url, myurl[0].strip())
        item['image_urls'] = [image_absolute_url]

        return item
```

---

This is the error i am getting. I am not able to find. Looks like its getting item but i am not sure

```
ERROR

File "/app_crawler/crawler/pipelines.py", line 9, in get_media_requests
            for image_url in item['image_urls']:
        exceptions.TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: can you post your full erorr too?

Comment: In `parseUserProfile`, print image_absolute_url to see if that actually contains anything.

Comment: it has this `[u'http://www.example.com/images/12.gif']` @Talvlin myfriend are you online for sometime , i have few more problems, i am going to post soon.

Comment: Christmas party tonight I'm afraid, but I'll be online late tonight or tomorrow morning.

Comment: Can you post all of your code to Pastebin or somewhere like that? I've managed to get a normal pipeline to work (well, at least to get to the point where it tries to download and image and then fails), so I'm not sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: The diff i have is that i am subclassing from initSpider not BaseSpider. I will paste my code. can you show me your code which is working

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a method in your pipelines.py
The said file contains 3 methods:

- Process item
- get_media_requests
- item_completed

The item_completed method is the one that handles the saving of the images to a specified path. This path is set in the settings.py as below:

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = ['scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline']
IMAGES_STORE = '/your/path/here'
```

Also included in the settings.py as seen above is the line that enables the imagepipeline.

I've tried to explain it in the best way I understood it as possible. For further reference, have a look at the official scrapy [documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/images.html).

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm. At no point are you appending `item` to `items` (although the example code in the documentation doesn't do an append either, so I could be barking up the wrong tree).

Try adding it to `parse(self, response)` like so and see if this resolves the issue:

```
for site in sites:
    item = PanduItem()
    item['username'] = site.select('dl/dd/h2/a').select("string()").extract()
    item['number_posts'] = site.select('dl/dd/h2/em').select("string()").extract()
    item['profile_link'] = site.select('a/@href').extract()

    items.append(item)
```

Comment: i tried everything but i am not getting pipelines to work. look like item object is not reaching pipeline. its not only imagepipeline but even normal pipeline have same error . crawling is ok , all other thing is ok but my items are not reaching my pipelines

Answer (score 0):

And set the IMAGES_STORE setting to a valid directory that will be used for storing the downloaded images. Otherwise the pipeline will remain disabled, even if you include it in the ITEM_PIPELINES setting.

For example:

```
IMAGES_STORE = '/path/to/valid/dir'
```